# Iterate array objects in structural directives

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I'm working with this accordion.

```
<ngb-accordion [closeOthers]="true" activeIds="static-0">
  <ngb-panel id="static-{{i}}" title="{{panel.title}}" *ngFor="let panel of (panels | search:'panel,content':query);let i = index;">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      <div class="row"><div class="col col-9">{{panel.content}}</div> <div class="col col-3"><figure (click)="open(modalId)"><img [src]="panel.imgsrc"></figure></div></div>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

What I want to do is to open a modal when I click on `figure` with the correspondent `panel.imgsrc` zoomed. For the modal, I'm using this.

```
<ng-template #modalId let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <figure><img src="assets/img/unidade1.png"></figure>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

The modal works, but only if I specify a static url in `(click)="open(modalId)"` and it matches exactly in `<ng-template #modalId`.

I tried using `#{{modalID}}` but it won't open; it won't show console errors but it's probably interpolation error.

I also thought about reverse engineering `ng-template` and changing the way it binds the ID of the modal so I can iterate array objects with proper notation, but I have no idea where it's the template or where they build the directives (anyway, there's probably a much easier way to do it).

I appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why I didn't try this before, but the solution is pretty simple.

```
<ngb-accordion [closeOthers]="true" activeIds="static-0">
  <ngb-panel id="static-{{i}}" title="{{panel.title}}" *ngFor="let panel of (panels | search:'panel,content':query);let i = index;">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      <div class="row"><div class="col col-9">{{panel.content}}</div> <div class="col col-3"><figure (click)="open(modal)"><img [src]="panel.imgsrc"></figure></div></div>

      <ng-template #modal let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <figure><img [src]="panel.imgsrc"></figure>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
        </div>
      </ng-template>

    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

I just needed to also iterate the `img` tag inside the modal as well, the `id` should be the same since it's looping as well.
If someone does this, I suggest styling the `figure img`to `max-width:100%` so it won't overlap the modal's box.